# OpenCV4Android - Displaying text on created rectangles

Tags: android, c++, opencv, rectangles

I would like to know if there is any simple way to display text on created rectangles. I have my rectangles stored in array:

```
Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++) {    
        Core.rectangle(mRgba, facesArray[i].tl(), facesArray[i].br(), FACE_RECT_COLOR, 3);
    }
```

That means I have also x,y of each rectangle. I don't know methods which might allow me to display numbers on them. I want to display place of each rectangle in array on each rectangle, so I can create interface in the future that will let user to choose one of them. If you could help me or provide some useful source of knowledge which I can study in that matter/example I would be glad.

Comment: You probably want to use [`cv::putText()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html?#puttext).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++) {    
        Core.rectangle(mRgba, facesArray[i].tl(), facesArray[i].br(), FACE_RECT_COLOR, 3);
        Core.putText(mRgba, "Face"+i, new Point(facesArray[i].x, facesArray[i].y), 3, 1, new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 1);
    }
```

Worked for me